# No field configured for Model with name 'image_filename'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, solr, sunspot

I have a Model with 2 atrributes:

```
:image_filename 
:yt_video_id
```

I have this code in my controller:

```
def index
   @search = Model.solr_search do |s|
   s.fulltext params[:search]
   s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 2
   s.with(:image_filename || :yt_video_id)
   end
   @model = @search.results
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
 end
```

in my `model.rb` Model I have this in `searchable`:

```
searchable do
    string :image_filename, :yt_video_id
  end
```

I want filter `:image_filename` **OR** `:yt_video_id` any are not `"nil"`. I mean, both attributes must have a mandatory value.

but I get the error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError in ModelsController#index

No field configured for Model with name 'image_filename'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the following steps:

(This solution works fine for me. I hope this solution can help you too.)

In **model.rb** you can not write this syntax:

```
searchable do
    string :image_filename, :yt_video_id
  end
```

You must write this syntax:

```
searchable do
      string :image_filename
      string :yt_video_id
     end
```

In your **models_controller.rb** in index action:

```
def index
   @search = Model.solr_search do |s|
   s.fulltext params[:search]
   s.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 2
   s.any_of do
      without(:image_filename, nil)
      without(:yt_video_id, nil)
     end
   end
   @model = @search.results
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
   end
 end
```

I have used the `any_of` method.

**To combine scopes using OR semantics, use the any_of method to group restrictions into a disjunction:**

```
Sunspot.search(Post) do
  any_of do
    with(:expired_at).greater_than(Time.now)
    with(:expired_at, nil)
  end
end
```

You can see in https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Scoping-by-attribute-fields

Comment: Could you please explain why we can't write like this `string :image_filename, :yt_video_id` ?
[search-with-sunspot](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot)
In the video they have used that syntax, but for me that was not working.